# Splitting data into multiple columns in Hive

Tags: split, hive

How can I split a data string into 3 separate columns in a Hive table?

Example input data: `116:151:1`.  Split as `gid, sid, rid`.

Required output:

```
gid    sid     rid
116    151     1
```

Answer (score 15):

Use the `split()` function.  You can read about it (and all other Hive functions) in the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF).

**Query**:

```
select split("116:151:1", '\\:')[0] as gid
     , split("116:151:1", '\\:')[1] as sid
     , split("116:151:1", '\\:')[2] as rid
from database.table
```

**Output**:

```
gid    sid    rid
116    151    1
```

You'll want to replace "116:151:1" with the name of the column in your table.

Comment: So for many such records with different strings how does the syntax change? If I try the above given command my output has 116  151  1 replacing the other all  record values in the column.

Comment: Read the last sentence I wrote.

Comment: yeah i read.Thanks.Still I am trying to split data  column  into 3 columns.  One i have tried regex. But trying does regex_replace(split()) work n how.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you.  My answer is the answer.  Just do what I wrote in the answer except replace `"116:151:1"` with the name of the column that you want to split.

Comment: got the solution                                                                                   split(id1,':')[0],
split(id1,':')[1],
split(id1,':')[2],

Answer (score 0):

Using split + sub select solves the question:

```
SELECT t.vec[0] AS gid, t.vec[1] AS sid, t.vec[2] AS rid
FROM (SELECT split("116:151:1", "[:]") AS vec) AS t;
```

Produce this ouput in hive:

```
+------+------+------+--+
| gid  | sid  | rid  |
+------+------+------+--+
| 116  | 151  | 1    |
+------+------+------+--+
```

Greetings!