# How to create a column each word after splitting the sentence using Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have an address like below

223 11 MAIN BANGALORE 560910

I was able to split the above address into words in one column with using the function split in the code.

Split(address,' ')

However, I would like to create a column for each word.

How this can be done using Hive Query Language.

Comment: You can refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130104/splitting-data-into-multiple-columns-in-hive). I think it might help you.

Comment: It helps to an extent but I need a solution where we have hundreds of addresses where word count is more that the mentioned address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting data into multiple columns in Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130104/splitting-data-into-multiple-columns-in-hive)